# ESM default named import in @mui without having to manually write .default

Tags: next.js, material-ui, es6-modules, commonjs

I'm using node.js, next.js and @mui with `type: "module"` in `package.json`

```
import Add from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
console.log(Add)
{
    default: {
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.memo),
    type: { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.forward_ref), render: [Function] },  
    compare: null
    }
}
```

is it possible to automatically return `Add.default` without having to remove `type="module"` in `package.json`?

if i use `import { Add } from "@mui/icons-material"` it works as it should, however it loads all icons which in development leads to big performance issues

Comment: Are you using Typescript?

Comment: @JamesLawson nope.

Comment: In case you haven't already found this, there is an [open GitHub Issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/35233) discussing a similar problem. Unfortunately, right now there is not much activity but might be worth watching this Issue / contributing in case an answer appears there.

Comment: This seems to be a relatively new issue with ESM that is currently trending. After searching around I'm seeing a few other people discuss this: [(1)](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/1381) , [(2)](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/1642) , [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083446/typescript-import-esm-default-export) , [(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940391/how-do-i-make-a-esm-cjs-module-that-doesnt-require-adding-default-to-the-i) , [(5)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69694837/3649209)