# import inside Electron renderer script

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I followed the Electron typescript quick-start code structure. Basically I cloned the repo.
It worked fine until I wanted to split my code in multiple .ts files, and import them in the renderer script.

Then I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`. Because of this line on top of the renderer.ts:

```
import { stuff } from "./otherfile.ts";
```

After digging for more info, it seems that the reason is the `"module": "commonjs"` from tsconfig... But if I change that to `esnext` then Electron will not load the preload script anymore!

Has anyone actually managed to get Electron and typescript fully working? I mean, with being able to use import across multiple files and stuff like that?

---

### Minimal reproductible example:

file structure:

```
/dist
/dist/main.js
/dist/preload.js
/dist/renderer.js
/dist/stuff.js
/src
/src/main.ts
/src/preload.ts
/src/renderer.ts
/src/stuff.ts
/index.html
```

/src/main.ts:

```
import { ipcMain } from "electron"; // imports work fine in main
...

ipcMain.on(...
```

/src/preload.ts:

```
 import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer} from "electron"; // imports work fine in preload

 contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("my-api", { ....
```

/src/renderer.ts

```
 import stuff from "./stuff.ts"; // import fails in renderer (exports is not defined error)
```

/src/stuff.ts

```
 const stuff = { ... };
 export default stuff;
```

/index.html

```
 <html>
   ...
   <script src="./dist/renderer.js"></script>
 </html>
```

ts.config:

- if I change "module" to "es6", then preload.ts will not load.
- if I leave "module" to "commonjs" then imports in renderer.ts not work

If I manually add `var exports = {}` in `renderer.js` after ts compiles the file, then I get a different error "require is not defined"

Comment: Since the line you have identified as the error doesn't include `exports`, it is the file you're trying to import that produces the error. Please [edit] your question and include the relevant lines of the file with the problem; it would be even better if you could include a [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: But ESM doesn't use the variable `exports`, so I'm not sure how your error originates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, it's not possible the way that boilerplate is configured.

To use `import`/`require` inside of the `renderer` process, **you must either lower the default security settings in the latest versions of Electron OR use a transpiler so that the final code the `renderer` executes will not include `import`/`require`.**

And in the `electron-quick-start-typescript` project you'll find [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript/master/src/renderer.ts) that confirms that as the issue.

> // This file is required by the index.html file and will
> // be executed in the renderer process for that window.
> // No Node.js APIs are available in this process unless
> // nodeIntegration is set to true in webPreferences.
> // Use preload.js to selectively enable features
> // needed in the renderer process.

Node.js APIs include `import` and `require`.

Furthermore, when you do access `require`, if sandbox is enabled then you're actually getting a polyfilled version, not the underlying `require` - [see these notes about preload script sandboxing](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload#augmenting-the-renderer-with-a-preload-script)

Your only other option short of changing boilerplates is to access anything you need via the preload script like `window.api.yourFunction` instead.

---

You may wish to use a boilerplate which includes transpilation via Webpack to enable you to use `import` inside of your renderer process.

I believe both of these boilerplates accommodate it (and I can probably advise you somewhat if you get stuck with one of them)

- **https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate** (I recommend this one)
- https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template

---

*PS - If you're writing code intended for distribution to others, please do not enable `nodeIntegration` as it breaks the security model of Electron!*

*PPS - You can also try `"module": "ES2020"`, which is what we use - but it will not fix your issue of not being able to `import`/`require` within the `renderer` process.*

Comment: tx, electron-react-boilerplate works... I don't like all the additional webpack stuff, the entire thing has like 1.5 GB and 60k files, but apparently this is the javascript world now and there is no other way around it :(

Comment: The wonders of transpilation! I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

I believe your error is caused by confusing CommonJS (CJS) and ES modules (ESM). It sounds like you are using CJS exports with ESM imports which is not  compatible. The next section is a working Election example and after that is a comparison of CJS and ESM exports (export) and require (import).

## Working Solution

Your OP did not include any code so this is my best guess at what the issue was and provides a working solution. Start by setting up the code:

```bash
# Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript
# Go into the repository
cd electron-quick-start-typescript
# Install dependencies
npm install
```

Next create the following file:

```
// src/otherfile.ts
export const stuff = {
    fullOf: 'stuff'
}

export function shareLocation(loc: string): void {
    console.log(`I was imported by: ${loc}`);
}
```

Now open the `src/main.ts` file and make the following changes:

```
// Add import to top of file.
import {stuff, shareLocation} from "./otherfile"

// Add this code to the end of the createWindow() function.
shareLocation('main.ts (main.js)');
```

Now if you run this example with `npm start` you will see `I was imported by: main.ts (main.js)` in your terminal.

If you tried to do this with the `src/preload.ts` file you will get an error because of sandboxing. To see this, make the following change in `src/preload.ts`:

```
// Add to first line.
import {stuff, shareLocation} from "./otherfile";

// Add after the for loop inside the DOMContentLoaded function.
shareLocation('preload.ts (preload.js)');
```

Now if run `npm start` you will get an error in the electron window (web browser) console. **This is because of important security settings within Electron.** Make the following change to your `src/main.ts` file:

```
// Modify the webPreferences of the new BrowserWindow.
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      sandbox: false // <=== ADD THIS LINE
    },
    width: 800,
});
```

Your import will work as intended now and you should see `I was imported by: preload.ts (preload.js)` in the electron window (web browser) console. **Keep in mind this code is insecure!** You should [use IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) instead of disabling the sandbox.

If you are still getting an error I believe it is because your confusing CommonJS (CJS) and ES modules (ESM). It sounds like you are using CJS exports with ESM imports. See the next section that demos the difference.

## CommonJS (CJS) vs ES modules (ESM)

#### CommonJS (CJS)

CommonJS was the original method for exporting and requiring (importing) modules in Node. It was a standard introduced by Mozilla engineer Kevin Dangoor in 2009. You would write some code in one file like so:

```js
// example.js
function hello() {
    console.log('World!');
}
module.exports = hello;
```

And then require (import) the code into another module/file like so:

```js
// main.js
const hello = require('./example.js');
hello();
```

Just like ES modules, which is a newer standard, "you can export `functions`, `var`, `let`, `const`, and `classes`" ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#exporting_module_features)). Here is an bigger example that exports two functions using a single export `object`:

```js
// example.js
function hello() {
    console.log('World!');
}
function foo() {
    console.log('Bar!');
}
module.exports = {
    hello,
    foo
};
```

We could even change the exported `object` to refer to our functions by a different name. We could change the export code to this for example:

```js
module.exports = {
    H: hello,
    F: foo
};
```

We would then require (import) this code like so:

```js
// main.js
const {hello, foo} = require('./example.js');
hello();
foo();

// OR with the other export example
const {H, F} = require('./example.js');
H();
F();
```

#### ES Module (ESM)

This is the modern approach to including JavaScript code from one file/module into another, and is designed to work in modern browsers. If you were manually writing JavaScript modules for the web you would have to add the `type="module"` attribute to the script tag that loads your module.

In your setup, and many others, you have bundlers (webpack for example) of some kind that handle this for you by compiling/transpiling your code for you. This topic is out of scope to this question though, so lets look at an example.

Using ESM our simple example now becomes:

```js
// example.js
function hello() {
    console.log('World!');
}
export default hello;
```

Notice how our export statement has changed. To keep things simple I provide a `default` export when exporting a single item. We can also inline the export:

```js
// example.js
export default function hello() {
    console.log('World!');
}
```

And then we import the code into another module/file like so:

```js
// main.js
import hello from "example";
hello();
```

If you do not want to use `default` in your exported module you will have to use a different syntax for importing your code. As [Darryl Noakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15261914/darryl-noakes) mentions, that would be [Named Exports](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910). Since this is a TypeScript project this includes changing your TypeScript config. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68941219/3193156) covers what to do if you want to go this route with this project.

If you export multiple items you do not have to use the `default` statement:

```js
// example.js
function hello() {
    console.log('World!');
}
function foo() {
    console.log('Bar!');
}
export {
    hello,
    foo
}
```

And you import the code in a similar fashion to [object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
// main.js
import {hello, foo} from "example";
hello();
foo();
```

For additional help with `import` this [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) is a great start as well as this [Free Code Camp Article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/modules-in-javascript). JavaScript Tutorial has a [great tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-object-destructuring/) on what object destructing is. This [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports) goes more into module imports including **why they are not actually using destructing**. Thanks again to [Darryl Noakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15261914/darryl-noakes) for pointing that out!

Comment: You do not _have_ to use a default export if you are exporting only one item; you can still use a named export. A default export is never a requirement, it just determines how you import the module.

Comment: Also, your last code example is incorrect. There should be no equals sign. And it is _not_ object destructuring, it only looks similar.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes thanks for the comments! Fixed my code mistakes and changed my accidental misinformation. Thanks for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 1):

Electron doesn't fully support ECMAScript modules yet, but this should not impact your Typescript code, which can be very modern.

**OPTION 1 (LOOSE FILES)**

Do this in your index.html to bootstrap your renderer process's Typescript code, as in [this initial sample of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample1). This will get you up and running quickly, though it uses node integration, which should be disabled before you release to production:

```html
<body>
   <div id='root' class='container'></div>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
        require('./built/renderer');
   </script>
</body>
```

**OPTION 2 (BUNDLED)**

To get rid of the require statement, and operate closer to an SPA, in line with Electron security recommendations, you can use webpack bundling and reference built Typescript as follows, as in [this updated sample of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final):

```html
<body>
    <div id='root' class='container'></div>

    <script type='module' src='vendor.bundle.js'></script>
    <script type='module' src='app.bundle.js'></script>
</body>
```

**SETTINGS**

I specify `type=commonjs` in package.json and `module=commonjs` in the tsconfig.json file, whereas in non-Electron projects I use ECMAScript module settings instead, to build slightly better output.

The art of it of course is to produce a modern code setup that you can grow according to your own preferences, rather than being limited to what starter projects do.